# Cucumber junit failing with error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at gherkin.GherkinDialectProvider

Tags: cucumber-junit

I configured Cucumber with Selenium, I added all the features, Class Definitions, Test definitions everything. When I execute the code, it throws error stating -

I already tried checking gherkin and cucumber version , I use cucumber version 4 and gherkin 4. I tried with gherkin 6 version as well. Didn't work.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/deps/com/google/gson/Gson
at gherkin.GherkinDialectProvider.
 <clinit>(GherkinDialectProvider.java:17)
at gherkin.TokenMatcher.<init>(TokenMatcher.java:25)
```

It should display the features.

Answer (score 0):

**Gherkin** is a transitive dependency which we shall not add explicitly in pom.xml

**Key Point:** We shall not mix direct & transitive dependencies specially their versions! Doing so can cause unpredictable outcome.

**Solution:** In case you are adding below dependencies, please remove. **cucumber-core**, **cucumber-java**, **cucumber-jvm-deps**, **gherkin** and **Junit**. They're transitive dependencies and will be provided by your dependencies.

You can add below set of cucumber minimal dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Save pom.xml and Sync new dependencies at project level by

- Doing Right click (on windows)
- Click on **Maven**
- Click on **Update Project**
- Select Check box - Force update of Snapshots/Releases & Click Ok

And finally run mvn clean test.

Comment: I am running it as a Junit test. Also, I am adding jar files directly from build path -> Add external jar file. Will that work? Because I saw that all the above dependencies are necessary

Comment: Answer follows JUnit. Are you not using Maven.

Answer (score 0):

> I already tried checking gherkin and cucumber version , I use cucumber version 4 and gherkin 4. I tried with gherkin 6 version as well. Didn't work.

Have you tried 5?